# XML schema design: Choice of similar sequences without violating Unique Particle Attribution?

Tags: xml, xsd, unique

Schema novice here, I reckon I am going about this the wrong way:

I would like to create an .xsd schema that works across a range of products who may have one or more elements in common.

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice id="Media_Type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Media" fixed="12in"/>
      <xs:element name="rpm" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="label" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="tracks" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Media" fixed="7in"/>
      <xs:element name="label" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="playtime" type="xs:duration" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

...so that I can have the following two records validate:

Record A:

```
<Media>12in</Media>
<rpm>45</rpm>
<label>StarStruck</label>
<tracks>2</tracks>
```

Record B:

```
<Media>7in</Media>
<label>PlatinumDunce</label>
<playtime>4:33</playtime>
```

Alas, the "Unique Particle Attribution" is violated. In my naive approach the forced choice between the sequences should identify the attribution just fine, but I can also see how a parser might not work like that.

How could this be approached in a better way?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is condense your existing content model into a single `sequence` and mark the `Media` and `label` elements as required and the rest as optional.

The reason the UPA rule is violated is because the rule works on the element's name and disregard the  element's data type and value. You can condense the `Media` element's two values (*12in*, *7in*) into a single `union` type and use that as the element type for `<Media>` (I called it 'TwelveOrSevenIn' below). The full schema is quoted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:simpleType name="TwelveOrSevenIn">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="12in" />
      <xs:enumeration value="7in" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="MediaType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Media" type="TwelveOrSevenIn" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="rpm" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="label" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="tracks" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="playtime" type="xs:duration" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Record" type="MediaType" />
</xs:schema>
```

The above schema validates both:

```
<Record>
   <Media>7in</Media>
   <label>PlatinumDunce</label>
   <!-- "4:33" is represented this way in xs:duration -->
   <playtime>PT4M33S</playtime>
</Record>
```

and

```
<Record>
   <Media>12in</Media>
   <rpm>45</rpm>
   <label>StarStruck</label>
   <tracks>2</tracks>
</Record>
```

Edit: So there was one thing I left out regarding the UPA rule: it also takes into account the order of elements. One quick way to get around the UPA rule, is to change the order of the conflicting `Media` elements in one of the nested `sequences`s. This is perfectly valid for instance:

```
<xs:element name="Record">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice id="Media_Type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="rpm" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="Media" fixed="12in"/>
        <xs:element name="label" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="tracks" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Media" fixed="7in"/>
        <xs:element name="label" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="playtime" type="xs:duration" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

`rpm` comes before `Media` in the first sequence and that resolves the ambiguity, but if `rpm` needs to come after `Media` (or `Media` needs to come first in both sequences) then there's really no way around it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion - I had come across the 'restriction' before and this explains it very well.
However, if I read this correctly, with your proposed schema, the 7in record would also pass if 'playtime' was omitted, and the 12in record would pass if it carried a 'playtime' element? Neither of those are acceptable, sadly...

Comment: That type of validation is hard to model in XSD's, and might best be handled by application logic. XSDs are not great for constraining conditional logic that depends on the values on elements. XSD 1.1 has type alternatives but they only work on attributes. However, there is one way to get around the UPA rule and I edited my answer for that.

Comment: Much appreciated! I was worried that XSDs might just not be able to do this. Plan B is to factor these out into separate XSDs. _sigh_

Answer (score 1):

With XSD 1.1 you can have different content models for an element based on the value of an **attribute** of the element (look up "conditional type assignment"). So you could have different content models for `<Record type="LP"/>` and `<Record type="Single"/>`. But it can only depend on attributes of the element itself, not for example on attributes of the first child element.